# Rails - Join Table Will Not Autopopulate

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

My join table will not not autopopulate from the two tables that it is sourced from. I've spent about 5 hours trying to connect it in various ways to no avail. Any guidance on my code would be much appreciated.

Here is my code.

First Item:

```
`class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :orders_users
  has_many :users, :through => :orders_users

  validates :item, presence: true

end

def add_order(order)
end

def remove_order(order)
end

`
```

Second Item:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :orders_users
  has_many :orders, :through => :orders_users

  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  has_secure_password
end
```

The Migration:

```
class CreateJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_join_table :users, :orders do |t|
      t.index [:user_id, :order_id]
      t.index [:order_id, :user_id]
    end
  end
end
```

Orders Controller:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController


  def new
    binding.pry
    @order = Order.new
  end

  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    if @order.save
      redirect_to request.referer
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  def show
    @order
  end

  private

  def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(:item)
  end



end
```

Users Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      session[:current_user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to user_path(@user)
    else
      redirect_to new_user_path(@user)
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    session[:current_user_id] = nil
    @user.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
  end


  def index
    @user
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password,:password_confirmation)
  end


end
```

Comment: Its a bit unclear. Can you explain what you want to achieve with this ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Here's what I'm trying to do: When a user inserts an item into the database, I want a join table to record which user has entered which items into the database. Does that clarify my question?

Comment: I think after_save filter in order model will do what you required. Have you tried it ?

Comment: When you create an order , how are you specifying what user created it? Is that on the form somewhere?

Comment: The user is defined when I create the user in the user's controller. Then that user signs in and creates an order.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of how I would user after_save in this case? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have mixed the associations on the `Order` and the `User` models.

**You have 2 options.**

1. Remove the "has many through" and use HABTM (has and belongs to many)
2. Remove your jointable and create a new "real" OrderUser model

**Option 1**
Change your `User` and `Order` models to this:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users

  validates :item, presence: true

  def add_order(order)
  end

  def remove_order(order)
  end

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :orders

  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  has_secure_password
end
```

**Option 2 has_many through**

It should be `has_many` instead of `belongs_to`.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_users
  has_many :users, :through => :order_users

  validates :item, presence: true

  def add_order(order)
  end

  def remove_order(order)
  end

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_users
  has_many :orders, :through => :order_users

  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  has_secure_password
end
```

Rollback you db to remove the jointable

```
rake db:rollback
```

Remove the old migration file with the `JoinTable` migration.

Create a "real" model to use for "has_many through"

```
rails g model OrderUser order:references user:references
rake db:migrate
```

**Tip on how to verify the ActiveRecord relations**

Use the rails console, that way you don't have to be concerned about the controllers working correctly. A small example:

```
rails c
> u = User.create username: "test"
> o = u.orders.new item: "test-item"
> o.save
```

**Edit your order controller**

When creating the order you must specify the current_user on the order-object. In the example I'm using `current_user` to get the signed user, depending on your app you might have to change this.

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController


  def new
    @order = Order.new
  end

  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    @order.users.build(current_user) #current_user is a function returning the signed in user
    if @order.save
      redirect_to request.referer
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  def show
    @order
  end

  private

  def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(:item)
  end



end
```

Some info from the Rails guide about [has_many through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Comment: I did as you suggested to no avail. Any other suggestions would be much appreciated. Maybe I didn't catch something in your code because of the abbreviations. Thanks.

Comment: I've clarified the answer and the example a bit. The main-thing is that when using JoinTable migrations you shouldn't use "has_many through"

Comment: Thank you, Jacob. Here's what I'm trying to do: When a user inserts an item into the database, I want a join table to record which user has entered which items into the database. Does that clarify my question?

Comment: I've added an example of the OrderController. According to your comment above there is a signed in user that should be added to the order. In the example I used the very common function name "current_user" to get the signed in user. You might have to alter this according to your app